# NPM uninstalled package details still exist in package-lock.json - should I remove them?

Tags: npm, package.json, package-lock.json

```
npm uninstall react-dates --save
```

still leaves a lot of traces in package-lock.json - airbnb-prop-types for e.g. How do I remove them? Additionally, if it is the case that it is some other package which uses them, how do I find out which one it is?

Comment: Yes delete it from package.json if you do not need it anymore

Comment: How do I know which are the ones associated with the package I have uninstalled? Is there no other way than to remove them manually?